# Amidakuji (阿弥陀籤) simplification

Tags: code-golf, game, permutations

If you have ever had any exposure to Japanese or East Asian culture you will have surely encountered the Amidakuji game:

[image]

As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Leg), it is a type of lottery drawn on paper and used to randomly select a permutation of N items.

For example, it may be used to randomly assign a starting sequence to N people, or N prizes to N people, and so on.

The trick to understanding why the game represents a permutation is to realize that every horizontal stroke (called a "leg") **swaps** its two items in place.

The same Wikipedia page also explains that each permutation P of N items corresponds to an infinite number of Amidakuji diagrams. The one(s) with the least number of horizontal strokes (legs) are called the "primes" of that particular permutation P.

Your task is to receive an Amidakuji diagram with 2 or more vertical lines (in this example they are 6) in this format (minus the letters):

```
A B C D E F
| | | | | |
|-| |-| |-|
| |-| |-| |
| | | | |-|
| |-| |-| |
| | |-| |-|
| | |-| | |
|-| | |-| |
|-| |-| | |
| |-| | |-|
| | | | | |
B C A D F E
```

And produce one of its primes (again, minus the letters):

```
A B C D E F
| | | | | |
|-| | | |-|
| |-| | | |
| | | | | |
B C A D F E
```

The first and last lines with the letters are **not** part of the format. I have added them here to show the permutation. It is also **not** required that the first or last lines contain no legs `|-|`, **nor** that the output be as compact as possible.

This particular input example is one of the (infinite) ASCII representations of the Amidakuji diagram at the top of the Wikipedia page.

There is one non-obvious rule about these ASCII diagrams: adjacent legs are forbidden.

```
|-|-|  <-  NO, this does not represent a single swap!
```

Wikipedia explains a standard procedure to obtain a prime from a diagram, called "bubblization", which consists of applying the following simplifications over and over:

1) Right fork to left fork:

```
| |-|      |-| |
|-| |  ->  | |-|
| |-|      |-| |
```

2) Eliminating doubles:

```
|-|        | |
|-|   ->   | |
```

I am not sure whether that explanation is unambiguous. Your code may use that technique or any other algorithm that produces the required primes.

**Shortest code wins.**

Standard rules and standard allowances apply. (If the input is not valid, your program may catch fire. Input/output formats may be stdin/stdout, string argument, list of lines, matrix of chars, whatever works best for you, etc.)

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting challenge. I might take a while producing an ungolfed solution, heh.

Comment: Does the output need to be as compact as possible or is any amount of vertical space allowed as long as the number of legs is minimal?

Comment: @Laikoni any amount of vertical space is allowed.

Comment: Do bubblization and inverse bubblization reach every same result Amidakuji ?

Comment: @l4m2 what is inverse bubblization?

Comment: @Tobia insert doubles

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>322</s> 240 bytes

```python
def f(X):
 X=[[c>' 'for c in s.split('|')]for s in X.split('\n')];h=L=len(X[0])-1;p=range(L)
 for x in X:p=[a-x[a]+x[a+1]for a in p]
 while h:h=i=0;exec"if p[i]>p[i+1]:print'|'+i*' |'+'-|'+(L-i-2)*' |';h=p[i],p[i+1]=p[i+1],p[i]\ni+=1\n"*~-L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJNj5swED3Hv2KUi3GI05BV9@DUK60q9ZTTdlVFIhwQOIurYCwg2VRN@9ezY0NJutqq0oKwh@f5eH4z9kdbVGZxPudqC9tgzQSBtYzj7I4C3VY1ZKANNLPG7nQb0BNliUMbh67/oBuD8LKQK7lTJljH84TxaGllnZonFawYARdz9DHCyjjlxzhNQlzCyKdL3ZFNCDwXeqegEIXUcr5UR5WN9RZsrJM7XNBb2FqbFnmEekIBN8pxCVZc8wXzCPJw/tPOX3ab@0s2Rocy2pjx5DdfnR9BAqX0xE/Qf2SwwNvd@xZ@8e9sh/PhjwzeMMRe/LsXKxOiS1vVLaBMeVUS1wGr6vJLVZe@ESNsBHYhbMK@F2@pfqX5h8WV5st7GbueRGT0SvzwJ8oEVMynqB3uPJoiwKmIfsXHeDFJRRKLm@Svxoxq1e5rNImn@aTMfanzNDD78ttKG9VMAc2H6rlxvGvVoLgxhnX9dAwRY596H3QZ1V7@2fdK45kXYJYVlc5UQIFzylx17ap3FxoK8YgxDMepMFULFF29kwBXNMSqbjbw6zMzZ1/4O9H6E@TTXaZVTdvpbZHTVQcQcMMGVF49dEChz5QVdXD7MTx4yocLZXdry9iQZv2vSDvTJlfH4MD@k2JI8KDyfaZy8R4y2@ubvZsJ6RKMH1E8@Jw2SsCYeCUf2XD4tSpVP92gjmlpd6oRY/KqtTdOeh86jNXtNJpjrfP5BQ)

A function which takes the string in the specified form, and prints out the reduced Amidakuji in that form as well.

The basic idea here is to first convert the input into a permutation (in the `for x in X` loop); and then in the `while` loop, perform a bubble sort of that permutation, since as the wikipedia article notes, this results in a 'prime' Amidakuji.

Comment: Wow. I just spent a long time making a Python 3 version, but it's 526 bytes, heh.

Comment: I just fed hundreds of random diagrams to your code and I can confirm that it outputs correct primes!

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 288 bytes

```hs
p x(_:[])=x
p(x:y:z)(_:b:c)|b=='-'=y:p(x:z)c|0<1=x:p(y:z)c
c 0='-'
c _=' '
_#1="|"
m#n='|':c m:(m-1)#(n-1)
p?q=(p:fst q,snd q)
f%b|b==f b=b|0<1=f%f b
f l=reverse$snd$(g 0)%(foldl p[1..n]l,[])where n=1+div(length$l!!0)2;g b((x:y:z),a)|x>y=y?g(b+1)(x:z,a++[b#n])|0<1=x?g(b+1)(y:z,a);g _ x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BcoMgEL3zFdtoRhg1oz3S0Bx6bU89ZjKOKJpMkRC1KWb8d4sxsTmUHZbHe49ddp82X0LKYdBgcEK3O8IM0tjQjl6IJTjNSM8Z80KPdXQULiTro3XMjL2NpgxlEI26PRPmgYcSJ2aLfoEqRzGv92gGFcVVGBMHK5uR3pwY1rRoWjgFjcrhRFCx5GObAjjj1/LF0mJUgGS1OIu6Ea51uriEiCxxcZS5BL2NVyu1k4H99c9e1AIUi/38cMZSqLLdu/LpKSLPLyVwfJsoSElvXjvWbUrM/ZiM8wSp72@5o3ZkmusudaNE7OsEDDNDlR4UMMiPCG7LwDqEUrRvR9UK1TazUKX6A/R3@9nW7wpcKADLgxINGIKGHuZAfWjztNGM4Iqn@I//80/4XufuCR94mBX02PcX)

#### Explanation

```hs
-- the function p performs the permutation of a list
-- according to a single line from amidakuji board
p x (_:[]) = x
p (x:y:z) (_:b:c)
    | b == '-' = y : p (x : z) c
    | otherwise = x : p (y : z) c

-- helper to select either leg '-' or empty cell
c 0 = '-'
c _ = ' '

-- the # operator generates an amidakuji line containing one leg
-- which corresponds to one swap during bubble sort

-- terminal case, just one edge left
_ # 1 = "|"
-- each cell contains an edge '|' and either space or a '-' for the "active" cell
m # n = '|' : c m : (m - 1) # (n - 1)

-- helper to find the limit value of a function iteration
f % b
    | b == f b = b  -- return the value if it is unchanged by the function application 
    | otherwise = f % f b -- otherwise repeat

-- helper to appropriately combine q which is the result of invocation of 
-- the function g (see below), and a character p
p ? q = (p : fst q, snd q)

-- the function that does the work
f l = reverse $ snd $ (g 0) % (foldl p [1..n] l, []) where
    -- number of lines on the board
    n = 1 + div (length $ l !! 0) 2
    -- apply one iteration of bubble sort yielding (X, Y)
    -- where X is partially sorted list and Y is the output amidakuji
    g b ((x:y:z), a)
        -- if we need to swap two elements, do it and add a line to our board
        | x > y = y ? g (b + 1) (x:z, a ++ [b # n])
        -- if we don't need to, just proceed further
        | otherwise = x ? g (b + 1) (y:z, a)
    -- terminal case when there is only one element in the list
    g _ x = x
```

Comment: Good job! I fed 1000s of random diagrams to your code and it solved them all.

Comment: `(_:[])` can be just `[_]` and `p?q=(p:fst q,snd q)` can be `p?(f,s)=(p:f,s)`.  Instead of defining `c 0='-';c _=' ';` and then using `c m`, `" -"!!(0^abs m)` should work.

Comment: `(g 0)` does not need  brackets and a `let` in a guard is shorter than `where`. All together 274 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LboMwELz7K5ZHhC0ggh7duDn02p56RBThYEhU46BAIxP53ymEhORQr7we74zHs8/bHyHlMDSgkyxlGjVY055eCM4opztiOGNe6LGeTsSF7Ey0iZkeb5NohzInZraxUe0o5hmP2hDaloWj75y3UBOK6zAmDlZjR80Wl0FLGG7odKJyxSf7EjjjV9tyNWJUgjRSdKBY7BeHM5ZCVd3elZYVkZfXCji@RQxyYvRbz/pthbkfkylgkPt@wh2VkjnoneonioyvM9BMs5M4i1Mr3FYVbgXRCpdHWUhokni9VqkMkpQMdX5QwKA4IrgtDZsQKtG9H1UnVNcuRJ03n9D8dl/d6UOBCyVgeVCiBU3QYGApZMKxzxstCK54rv/mD/2M7z53Tfg0h4VBz//@AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Your fixpoint function `%` can be inlined with `until(\x->g 0 x==x)(g 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 105 bytes

```
$
¶$%`
r`.?.\G
 1$.'$*
+r-1=`\|(-?.?[- 1]*¶.*)(1+)
$2$1
-
 
1G`
;{`\b(1+) \1
$1-$1
*`1+
|
(1+)-(1+)
$2 $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYsxDsIwDEX3fwoPRrSJHMmsCHXsIQiSQWJgYYjYyLl6gF4sJbQKC7Js/f/8f7q/Hs9rKYx54p0hWRhCHEHKYc8OPomeLOZOhjCchfTi5im4vlPfgw@sEBB0NBzfFm8VU1SwyuflTD0yKpStQKylZMm0LZqir17nH//lV125NIeWptatdwE) Explanation:

```
$
¶$%`
```

Duplicate the last line.

```
r`.?.\G
 1$.'$*
```

Number the columns in the last line.

```
+r-1=`\|(-?.?[- 1]*¶.*)(1+)
$2$1
```

Move the numbers up until they get to the first line. At each iteration, only the rightmost number `-1=` is moved. It is moved to the rightmost `|` unless it is preceded by a `-` in which case it is moved to the previous `|`. (The `r` indicates that the regex is processed as if it was a lookbehind, which makes it marginally easier to match this case.) This calculates the permutation that the Amidakuji transforms into sorted order.

```
-
 
1G`
```

Keep just the list of numbers, deleting the `-`s and anything after the first line.

```
;{`
```

The rest of the program then is then repeated sort the list back into order, but the final list is not printed, however as it takes an iteration for Retina 0.8.2 to notice that the list is in order, a line with no legs is generated at the end, which I believe is acceptable.

```
\b(1+) \1
$1-$1
```

Mark all available pairs of adjacent unsorted numbers with `-`s for the legs.

```
*`1+
|
```

Print the legs but with the numbers replaced with `|`s.

```
(1+)-(1+)
$2 $1
```

Actually perform the swaps.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to run your code with [Retina.exe](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/blob/master/Retina.exe)? I think I have the correct source (105 bytes) but it outputs nothing. I tried the Hello World from the [Retina examples](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/tree/master/Examples) and it works. Can you upload the source somewhere, or Base64 encode it and put it in a pastebin, in case I got the encoding wrong?

Comment: @Tobia Sorry, but I can't remember how to use Retina.exe; I think I might have used it once or twice but these days I just use Try It Online.

Comment: LOL I'm dumb! I was using some cutting-edge version instead of 0.8.2. Now I got my harness to fed hundreds of random diagrams to your code and I can confirm that it always outputs the correct primes. Good job!

Comment: @Tobia Thanks for testing! Tweaks needed for Retina 1: `$*` → `*`; `-1=` → `0`; `1` → `_`; `;` → `.` (roughly); `*` → ``*\``.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>524</s> <s>488</s> 486 bytes

*-38 bytes thanks to ovs!*

```python
from numpy import*
A=array;E=array_equal
K=[0]
def r(a,m,n):
	X=len(m);Y=len(m[0]);W,H=a.shape
	for x in range(W-X+1):
		for y in range(H-Y+1):
			if E(a[x:x+X,y:y+Y],A(m)):a[x:x+X,y:y+Y]=A(n)
	return a
def p(a):
	b=A([[j>" "for j in i]for i in[i.split("|")for i in a.split("\n")]])
	while E(a,b)<1:a=b;Z=K*3;O=[0,1,0];T=[K+O,O+K]*2;D=[O,O],[Z,Z];P=[Z,O],[O,Z];*R,_=T;_,*L=T;b=r(r(r(r(r(r(a[any(a,1)],R,L),*D),*P),L,R),*D),*P)
	for i in a:print("",*[" -"[j]for j in i[1:-1]],"",sep="|")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDRasIwFH22XxHy1LQ3sm5vzTIQHAwUFBGmZkEiqzNiYxaVWfDfXdJOZXsZob3n3HOScxNb7Vdb83A@L922ROZQ2grp0m7dPok6XDmnKvbc1HnxeVCbqMfFnYzeiyVysYISDMmj1oRvChOXhE0b4C2EvcILV@3dStkiai23Dh2RNsgp81HEr3SSZmFnLVQ34YVOf4SWXqLnWIljfkwnUOVVOpXQ8SEk/93kndiQqOWK/cEZpOrZbKzCIQuvCbF@wgiHnHXI0TJA7aHQ7Z3d6H2MT5hcmkhdmm8GEyn9yV8rvSnCLLAgj1mu@ILNeC95YAP/FpDBnWRjLnrpAAZpTyb3rMuFxxLEDGaSDbmvgQ0CS0Yw52M2h6Tvy4K7@LaUUKbyMRmRMII@gaTrvyGBPoyupHnLZtTcOm38qBgSgRHFYi1v9xRZTjMpwau7wvJwybP1XnyiJ1Qveorqf8MumNaYXll0daN//H899JfHJ5PzNw)

This converts the Amidakuji to a 2D binary array, and directly reduces it using the rules.

Comment: I'm curious about your approach; I'll take a look! In the meantime, you can save some bytes by replacing `" "+i.replace("|","")+" "` with `i.split("|")` in . the first line of your `p` function...

Comment: A few more standard python golfing tweaks to get it to [479 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwEDyHr7B8souJgnKDUCmHnLkmca1qUaExAuM6RAUp6q9TG0qSqtXK3vHs7Mu6b0@NWg9DYZoaqUuteyRr3ZgWPXnbBIyBPt5N/jX/uEDlveUFMgRYzRSNvMU@qXJFahofJsBXgnqLojGoQ1IhA@o9J7A8n0DnNhbs/dCljYr@ryIUweFHsZAF2hHgXdT5e9ZHvX8QbGtb0eg3mWyJsj1N3l6MQjBOqAm4IpmNcV4@Y4Rdw9I1lMJBaSGXy7OuZEvwFdOZRDCTLwpT4bb5PMkqd7OwjG7CCJIsPiZ2mad1nFrPQrYScZYY4gz4F1QVgU3IoJPnJKSC8SNL7Z2yo6DOpSM1PmwZ3xK@9WzETnd/TZH5S6f5Im2kGof27VmWjVSEYxRgXor7ljyMgtBmOg0dNMEYX9HNvGtg7@l4N4RGPNl//F0/4bnOrAkeeHSLeA997RR0@AY).

Comment: [Looks like my algorithm is suboptimal...](https://tio.run/##hVBBb4MgFD7XX0E4wYSmpDetS3ro2WtbRhbMdMUoOmozTcz@ugNc23Q7LATe9773wfce7dCdGr2epsI0NdCXuh2AqtvGdOAp2CbSGDnEuzm@5h8XWQVveQEMkqQmGkfBYp9UuUY1jg8z4CuBg0XRGNADpYGR@j1Hcnk@yTa3NboPmbvmFcNfBRP08KNYqALskOR91Id7MkRDeBBka61w9EgmW6Stp8m7i9FA@g5bJN0jma1xXj5DAJ1h6QyVcFBZyNXy3FaqQ3CE@EoCeSVfNMTCTfN5UlXueiEZ3rBIJll8TOwwT@s4tZEwshJxlhjkluRfsqqQ3DAie3VOGBaEH0lqz5QcBXYh9ZRP7DOhJUIbicdOd8/myvVL5/6i1ijtmw7tXpaN0ohDQCEvxX1KziLK7E2nwVOLIIQjHYFfdAz8OWdXTD2mtyy4qcE/@t8a@qCxznj6Bg "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Yah, not sure why that's happening...

Comment: Not always...sometimes right-fork to left-fork isn't doable, but left-fork to right-fork is. In that specific case, it's just a matter of doing the opposite there. Perhaps I need to do both?

Comment: [524 bytes and it works...it's ugly, though.](https://tio.run/##hVDRasMgFH1uvkJ80kVLQ9@SOuhD3wqBPrV1MgxLVkNiMpuyBMJ@vdNkbdcNNkTvOfee6/Fad82h0vPzOTNVCfSprDugyroyDXjwlkwaI7toNcbn9O0kC@8lzYBBkpRE49CbbFmRalTiaDcCPhPYm2SVAS1QGhipX1Mkp8eDrFNbo1s/cG2DovutCATdfSkmKgMrJHkbtv6WdGHn7wRZWisc3ifZEmnradLmZDSQwwtrJN0lia1xnj9CAJ1h7gyVcFBZyNX0WBeqQbCH@JIE8pJ80hALN837QRWpewtJ8CIIJUuiPbPDPMyj2EYSkJmINozblB@T2LeRDFhEa8a/8bEmooQZdFuSf8iiQHIRENmqIwuwIBuyxoTbBtu5J3uBXXAkHsiabP4oj/8/DhPWRulhQt/uaV4pjTgEFPJc3L6EByEN7KxOg881ghD2tAfDor03nCO7YDpgemXeVQ3@0f/U0DuNdcbnTw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Well, it's still shorter than your initial attempt :).

Comment: Sure, by two bytes. Gee, I thought this challenge would be way simpler.

Comment: @JosiahRyanW I don't think you have to do the opposite. Rather, you should add more vertical space whenever needed (or convert to an internal representation that doesn't use vertical space.) Here is the output in the failing example you posted: it still had 3 right forks and a double: https://pastebin.com/QFHBLjXg

Comment: With my representation, I think doing the opposite was easiest. I honestly don't think I attacked this in the right way; this is how I would do it if I were simply doing normal code.

Comment: Some changes I made: `a[~all(a<1,axis=1)]` to `a[any(a,1)]`, store things that were used multiple times (like `a.shape`) in variables and use `print`s `sep` argument instead of `str.join`.

Comment: Another eight bytes with `_,*L=*R,_=[K+O,O+K]*2` (remove `T=...`).

Comment: I wrote a test harness to feed random diagrams and check the answers. Yours seems to fail to find the prime in some cases. Here is one example: https://pastebin.com/iMudj29b

Comment: I give up. I officially don't really have an easy way to do this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 45 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌐φ²MC½↕uö∩┴║%≤Oo╧i╕ïô§ê{δ¿k>┴ê◘►╢lµ∙→Z↔8╨─(·£
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a9edfd4d43ab127594efc1ba25f34f6fcf69b88b9315887beba86b3ec1880810b66ce6f91a5a1d38d0c428fa9c&i=%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%0A%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C+%7C%0A%7C-%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%0A%0A%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%0A%7C-%7C%0A%7C-%7C%0A%7C-%7C%0A%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C-%7C+%7C+%7C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C-%7C%0A%7C+%7C-%7C+%7C%0A&a=1&m=1)